# Azure windows VM has lost access to azure sql server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

Overnight, without any changes to our infrastructure I appear to have lost access to azure sql servers from an azure windows VM.

I use this windows VM to run self hosted agents that run UI tests that require database access. I didn't need to configure anything to allow this VM to 'see' the other azure SQL servers and was able to use SSMS on this VM without any issues.

This is the command I am using to test the connection...

```
powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('sasepa.database.windows.net', 1433)) 'success'
Exception calling "Connect" with "2" argument(s): "No such host is known"
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
```

Predictably the SSMS 'Connect to Server' with the correct details also fails with the same error

What could be the issue here?

My azure sql server has the option `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server` set to Yes

The windows VM is 'Windows 10 Pro', build number 19041.450

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what it does but somehow I ended up with a 'private DNS zone' linked to the same network adapter as my VM.

Once I removed this DB access was restored between the VM and the azure sql server.